# how to get value from dropdown inside an html table cel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve value of dropdown in side an html table dynamically. This is my html

```
<tr>
 <td>ITMF-502</td>
 <td>PUMA</td>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>HALF FRAME/ METAL/ NB/ LOW PRICE</td><td>KOTTAWA</td>
 <td>
  <select name="loc" id="location0" class="form-control">
   <option value="BR000002">KOTTAWA</option>
   <option value="BR000007">NEGOMBO</option>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

this is my java script

```
var table = document.getElementById('Items');
var tableRowCount = $("#Items > tbody > tr").length;
for (var i = 1; i <= tableRowCount; i++) {
    var obj = {
        itemCode: table.rows.item(i).cells[0].innerText,
        currentLocation: table.rows.item(i).cells[5].innerText,
        newLocation: table.rows.item(i).cells[6].find("select").val()
    };
    items.push(obj);
}
```

But it doesn't happen.Anybody can tell how can i access that value. I need to access value, not text.

Comment: where's the #Items in your html?????

Comment: You can't call jQuery methods on DOM objects. Look in your JavaScript error console. It will tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: then you should loop through select box data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code

HTML

```
<tr>
 <td>ITMF-502</td>
 <td>PUMA</td>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>HALF FRAME/ METAL/ NB/ LOW PRICE</td><td>KOTTAWA</td>
 <td>
  <select name="loc" id="location0" class="form-control">
   <option value="BR000002">KOTTAWA</option>
   <option value="BR000007">NEGOMBO</option>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tableRowCount = document.getElementById('location0').length;;
for (var i = 0; i < tableRowCount; i++) {
    alert(document.getElementById('location0')[i].value);
}
```

Comment: i need to get a value of the item. this will show a text

Comment: how can i put a dynamic value as 'location0'

Answer (score 0):

I think the base problem is that your FOR ignores first row (the one with index 0). Also you add into items array that does not exist...

This is improved jQuery version:

```
var items = [],
    table = $(document.getElementById('Items')),
    tableRows = table.find('tr'),
    obj,
    tableRow;

for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    tableRow = tableRows.eq(i);

    obj = {
        itemCode: tableRow.find('td').first().text(),
        currentLocation: tableRow.find('td').eq(5).text(),
        newLocation: tableRow.find("select").val()
    };
    items.push(obj);
}

console.log(items);
```